# terminal and subprocess.run() show different behaviors for a command (osmfilter)

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, openstreetmap

I am seeing a peculiar behavior with osmfilter (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) which can be installed with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install osmctools
```

Lets assume I exported *map.osm* for a region from https://www.openstreetmap.org and I want to filter only highways from that file. The command I can use is:

```
$ osmfilter map.osm --keep='highway' > highways_terminal.osm
```

The file *highways_terminal.osm* contains info about the highways. I then tried to use Python to do the same with subprocess.run():

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["osmfilter", "map.osm", "--keep='highway'"]
resp = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)

with open("highways_subprocess.osm", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(resp.stdout)
```

But, *highways_subprocess.osm* contains no information other than "bounds".

Am I handling the quotes incorrectly?

Comment: Does `resp.stderr` contain an error message? What is the return code? Note that you can directly specify an output file via option `-o=<file>`. Also consider taking a loot at [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) instead which is faster and has more features than osmfilter.

Comment: `resp.stderr` has no message. `resp.returncode` is `0`. I did try `-o=<file>` but I still only get "bounds". Also, I could access osmium freely...didn't have to 'loot' :) jk ..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem (10 months later) and fixed it as

```
cmd = "osmfilter map.osm --keep='highway' -o=highways_subprocess.osm"
subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```